# Compiling shader variants taking days

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine

I am currently building my Unity game but it is taking very long. It has built about 50000 fp of 294912 fp after 11 hours which seems unnatural for a small game like mine. I have deleted every graphical thing in my game (lights, decals, fog etc.) but it is still as slow as before. i am using HDRP and the version is 2022.2.14. I have already reached out to the Unity Q&A but i get no reply.

I have for example enabled shader stripping and many other settings which are supposed to make the build process faster but it doesnt seem to help. i will never be able to upload the game if the build process is as slow as it currently is. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: this is going to sound like Im suggesting the colour of your socks matters. But try turning off optimize mesh data (seriously..)

Comment: Update to the latest LTS and then build.